# How to Close Dropdown, in onchange function called?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I use select box for choose email from drop down email list, if user select the email, i call a javascript function for call ajax, this ajax function return chosen email's imap function return value, everything is fine, but email drop down doesn't close when user choose email, when ajax response is completed after only it will close,

Here is my HTML Dropdown

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group m-form__group">
               <select name="info_email" id="info_email" class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker" data-live-search="true" onchange="get_mail_content_block(this.value);">
                <option value="">Choose Email</option>

                <?php 
                    $admindata = $this->session->userdata('admindata');
                    if ($admindata['email_id'] != '') {
                        $users_email_info = get_users_mail_details_if_exist($admindata['email_id']);    
                        if(count($users_email_info) > 0){
                            echo "<option value=".$users_email_info->email_detail_id.">".$users_email_info->email_ID."</option>"; 
                        }
                    }

                 ?>
                    <?php
                        if(!empty($email_lists))
                        {
                            foreach ($email_lists as $key => $email_list) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $email_list->email_detail_id; ?>" <?php if($default_email == $email_list->email_detail_id){ echo 'selected'; }else{ echo ''; } ?>><?php echo $email_list->email_ID; ?></option>
                            <?php }
                        }
                    ?>
               </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

above i call get_mail_content_block(id); Javascript function is

```
function get_mail_content_block(val)
{
    $('#mailbox_loader_img').show();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseurl+'Mailbox/email_content_block',
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    data:{'email_id':val },
    dataType: "html",

    success: function(response)
    {
        $('#mailbox_loader_img').hide();
        $('#mail_content_append_block').empty().append(response);   
    }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `async: false`, it is making the AJAX call synchronous, and blocking the entire browser (Javascript is single-threaded).

In any case synchronous AJAX is

a) completely unnecessary

and

b) deprecated, precisely because it causes these kinds of problems - some browsers will issue a warning in the Console if they see you are using it.

P.S. you've also added `type: "POST"` twice, which won't cause a problem, but is redundant.